# How to use arrays to summarize a data list

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

this is for my first programming class. So far we've only done conditional statements, loops, and file input and output. I'm pretty unsure of how to even solve this. Everything we've done before was pretty simple. I believe I have to use for loops with 2d arrays.

Assignment instructions: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e9292f14b2f8f71501ea
Data list: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e50fbf84fd74b355df07

I have to ask the user a max and min temperature and then using the data table file print out each month and percentage of days that fell withing that range. After that I have to have the program print out a recommendation to select the month that had the highest percentage. I know this part needs to be a for loop.

So far my code only has the printf and scanf to ask the user for lowest temp and highest temp. Any help or suggestions on how to set this up is appreciated.
Also I'm wondering if this is still considered pretty basic because I'm feeling lost.

Comment: The assignment basically has two parts: Reading file input and calculating the percentage. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: "I believe I have to use for loops with 2d arrays." The assignment states that "Arrays are not required (except for the name of the input file), but may simplify your solution." I think that you can assume that the input data is ordered by date. In that case, you don't need arrays. You can keep running counts of total days and days where the temperature falls within the specified reange. When the month or year change, do the calculation and reset the counts.

Comment: The question looks strangely familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144059/using-arrays-to-read-a-file-and-get-information, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147822/using-an-array-to-read-a-file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework spam.

Comment: Let's not throw the baby out with the bath water... Yes the OP could have presented more detail/code, but there is obviously an opportunity for learning here. I'll do a short writeup and give direction while leaving it homework.

Answer (score 1):

C can be a bit overwhelming at first, but with any language, C in particular, you simply break the task down into as small of pieces as possible, and then research what tools the language provides to do what you need to do. As correctly mentioned in the comments, you task is to basically read values from a data file and compute the percentage of flying days available for your temperature range each month.

Does that mean it will be an easy assignment -- No -- intentionally so. This is a good assignment to make you learn the basics of C, basic file I/O, loops, and yes basic array index handling. When your assignment says:

**Look at Requirements and Data**

Arrays are not required (except for the name of the input file), but may *simplify* your solution.

That word *simplify* should jump out of that hint at you. Why would that hint be given? What does it mean? As with any project, you have to analyze your data and your requirements to figure out how to approach the problem and what your options are. A careful look at the assignment will show you your data files contains 2 years of data laid out line-wise by day. The requirements want you to calculate to percentage of good flying days for the TOTAL number of days for any given month using the data for both years in arriving at your percentage.

**Consider Options**

How would you approach it without arrays? You would have to read the entire file to calculate the percentage for each month involved if you were simply going to store the best percentage and best month in a local variable. That would mean you would have to read the file 12 times to compute the max percentage, set the best month, and make a comparison between all 12 months.

How would you approach it if you used arrays? Well, what information do you need to compute the percentage of flying days for each month? The total number of days for the month, and the total number of flying days for each month (within your low/high temperatures).

**Think Through Implementation**

You know there are only 12 months, so if you had an array with 12 elements, that could represented the number of days available in each month with each element of the array (`0-11` - but note: the months are numbered `1-12` [Jan. - Dec.]). If you then kept another 12-element array of the flying days in each month, you could make all your calculations from the data stored in 2 simple 12 element single-dimensional arrays. The best part is you could fill both arrays on one-pass through the data file.

How would you count the days in the array slots for each month? Well, if you initialized all array element to `0`, you could simply add 1 to each element for each day and flying day you read from the file (you read the month for that line as the first number in each row) So as you read each line (reading month into `m`) you could do something simple like `totaldays[m] = totaldays[m] + 1;` (or just `totaldays[m]++;`) for each line of the file. You could use a simple temperature test and if the temp you read in the line is between your low/high flying temp, you could similarly do `flyingdays[m]++;`. After reading the whole file once, you have both arrays filled, one holding the total days for each month, the other holding the total flying days for each month.

(**NOTE**: again, array indexes are `0-11` (for 12 elements) while months are `1-12`, so you really need something like `totaldays[m-1]++;` and `flyingdays[m-1]++;`)

Then to complete your calculations, you could use a simple loop like `for (m = 0; m < 12; m++)` and calculate your percentage of flying days for each month and keep 2 simple variables (one `maxpercent`, and the other `bestmonth`) which you would test after you make the calculation for each month to ultimately arrive at the best flying month for your maiden flight. (remember if you are looping `0-11`, your month will now be `m + 1` to store in `bestmonth`, etc..

Lastly (and this should always be first, but it falls here in this explanation), you have to choose the `type` of storage for each of your variables. Now this should always be something on your mind when you start selecting storage `type`s for your variables, but it is also something you can fine-tune as you go. So don't get bogged down being overly concerned about it at the start if you are not that familiar with it yet, just rough-in your types with `int` or `unsigned int` for integer values, if the data fits, and take a harder look at it as your experience grows.

OK already, how? Same way you do it every time, you match the storage based on the size (or range of values) you will need to store. If your months are only between `1-12`, do you really need a whole `unsigned int` (with a range of `0 - 4294967295`) to store those values? Can a month be negative? If not, why would you use a signed `int` to hold the value? (there are valid reasons, just not here) So what is the smallest `unsigned type` that would be appropriate? An `unsigned char` holds values that range from `0 - 255`, so surely that would do...

**Prototype**

Now that you have sussed out your program requirements, looked at the values for your data, and thought threw the logic of what your code needs to do, it is finally time to pick up the keyboard. Looking at what you came up with you will have something that should look similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    /* declare & initialize variables */
    /* (hint) */
    unsigned char totaldays[12]  = {0};
    unsigned char flyingdays[12] = {0};


    /* prompt for input of t_low/t_high and filename */

    /* open file */

    /* read totaldays and flyingdays into array */
    /* (hint at an efficient way below)         */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%hhu %hhu %hu %f", &m, &d, &y, &t) == 4) {

    }

    /* close file */

    /* loop though each month and compute percentage, test for max, 
       set best month, print totals statistics for that month */
    /* (hint) */
    for (m = 0; m < 12; m++) {

    }

    /* finally print best month for maiden flight */

    return 0;
}
```

**Validate**

Finish the code and validate that your output matches the solution given in the assignment for `low = 60` and `high = 80`. Let me know if you run into problem and I'm happy to work with you further.

**A Bit More Explanation**

First, (a bit of `fscanf` logic) for your read loop, if you look at data file, you can read the month `m`, the day `d`, the year `y`, and then temp `t` into values if you want. That is with the following declared:

```
unsigned char  mbest, m, d, tl, th;
unsigned short y = 0;
float maxpct = 0.0, t = 0.0;
```

But if you look carefully at what you need to do, you never use the day `d` or year `y` in any computation. The `scanf` functions allow you to read and discard values with `%*u` (where `u` can be any type specifier, e.g. `d` for `int`, `c` for `char`, etc.) without those being added to the return (or successful match count returned by the `scanf` functions). So instead of declaring and reading `d` and `y`, you do without them and use:

```
unsigned char  mbest, m, tl, th;
float maxpct = 0.0, t = 0.0;
...
while (fscanf (fp, "%hhu %*u %*u %f", &m, &t) == 2)
```

Which just picks up `m` and `t` from each line for a total return (or match count) of `2`. With that background, your read loop could look like:

```
    /* read all values from file, update both arrays 
       NOTE: array[0] holds month 1 data
             adjust array index as needed */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%hhu %*u %*u %f", &m, &t) == 2) 
    {
        totaldays[m-1]++;     /* increment number of days for month m */

        if (tl <= t && t <= th)
            flyingdays[m-1]++;   /* increment flying days in month m */
    }
```

Notice, since we initialize our array values to `zero` to begin with, when we increment the value for any given month (`m-1` array index), we are just adding 1 to the count for that month.

Now for your computation loop. Having the total and flying days, you can now step through your arrays and easily compute the percentages for each month, in something similar to:

```
    for (m = 0; m < 12; m++)
    {
        float pct = (float)flyingdays[m]/totaldays[m] * 100; /* compute percent */

        if (pct > maxpct) {   /* if greater than max, update max & mbest */
            maxpct = pct;
            mbest = m + 1;
        }

        printf ("Month %2hhu: %5.1f percent of days in range.\n", m + 1, pct);
    }
```

**Note:** the `printf` above aligns the output slightly better than your requirements. If you want to exactly match your assignment output, you can use:

```
 printf ("Month %hhu: %.1f percent of days in range.\n", m + 1, pct);
```

Now, given that to work though, and given the day you have already spent working on it, I would bet you should be able to wrap up the rest. If not, drop another comment and we'll get you un-stuck.

**All the Pieces to the Puzzle**

Sometimes it really does help to see how all of the pieces of the puzzle can be fit together. In C there are always many ways to do just about anything, so this is just one approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    /* declare & initialize variables */
    char iname[31] = {0};
    unsigned char totaldays[12]  = {0};
    unsigned char flyingdays[12] = {0};
    unsigned char  mbest, m, tl, th;    /* types match size of data held  */
    float maxpct = 0.0, t = 0.0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    mbest = m = tl = th = 0;

    /* prompt for input of t_low/t_high and filename */
    printf ("Tell me about your dragon’s preferred temperature for flying:\n"
            "What is the coldest temperature they can fly in?\n");
    scanf ("%hhu", &tl);

    printf ("What is the hottest temperature they can fly in?\n");
    scanf ("%hhu", &th);

    printf ("Please enter the name of the weather data file for Dragon Island.\n");
    scanf (" %30[^\n]%*c", iname);  /* limit name to 30 chars */

    /* open file, or exit */
    if (!(fp = fopen (iname, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", iname);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read totaldays and flyingdays into arrays
       NOTE: array[0] holds month 1 data
             adjust array index as needed */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%hhu %*u %*u %f", &m, &t) == 2) 
    {
        totaldays[m-1]++;     /* increment number of days for month m */

        if (tl <= t && t <= th)
            flyingdays[m-1]++;   /* increment flying days in month m */
    }

    /* close file */
    fclose (fp);

    /* loop though each month and compute percentage, test for max, 
       set best month, print totals statistics for that month */
    for (m = 0; m < 12; m++)
    {
        /* compute percent */
        float pct = (float)flyingdays[m]/totaldays[m] * 100;

        if (pct > maxpct) {   /* if greater than max, update max & mbest */
            maxpct = pct;
            mbest = m + 1;
        }

        printf ("Month %2hhu: %5.1f percent of days in range.\n", m + 1, pct);
    }

    /* finally print best month for maiden flight */
    printf ("I recommend month %hhu for the Celebration of the First Flight!\n",
            mbest);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/dragonflight
Tell me about your dragon’s preferred temperature for flying:
What is the coldest temperature they can fly in?
60
What is the hottest temperature they can fly in?
80
Please enter the name of the weather data file for Dragon Island.
island.txt
Month  1:  66.1 percent of days in range.
Month  2:  71.4 percent of days in range.
Month  3:  72.6 percent of days in range.
Month  4:  98.3 percent of days in range.
Month  5:  95.2 percent of days in range.
Month  6:  48.3 percent of days in range.
Month  7:  48.4 percent of days in range.
Month  8:  11.3 percent of days in range.
Month  9:  63.3 percent of days in range.
Month 10: 100.0 percent of days in range.
Month 11:  83.3 percent of days in range.
Month 12:  77.4 percent of days in range.
I recommend month 10 for the Celebration of the First Flight!
```

**Debugging - The Final Step**

There are a number of ways to debug your program. Generally, when you are concerned with values, you can either simply dump intermediate values with `printf` or use a debugger like `gdb` to look at the values that way. For purposes here, let's look at some values. Simply add a couple of loops and a `printf` after you close the file. e.g.:

```
fclose (fp);

for (m = 0; m < 12; m++)
    printf (" totaldays[%2hhu] : %2hhu  flyingdays[%2hhu] : %2hhu  pct : %f\n",
            m+1, totaldays[m], m+1, flyingdays[m],
            (float)flyingdays[m]/totaldays[m] * 100);
```

With the validation temps entered:

```
temp low  : 60
temp high : 80
```

When you look at the intermediate values in each of the arrays, you should see:

```
 totaldays[ 1] : 62  flyingdays[ 1] : 41  pct : 66.129036
 totaldays[ 2] : 56  flyingdays[ 2] : 40  pct : 71.428574
 totaldays[ 3] : 62  flyingdays[ 3] : 45  pct : 72.580650
 totaldays[ 4] : 60  flyingdays[ 4] : 59  pct : 98.333336
 totaldays[ 5] : 62  flyingdays[ 5] : 59  pct : 95.161285
 totaldays[ 6] : 60  flyingdays[ 6] : 29  pct : 48.333332
 totaldays[ 7] : 62  flyingdays[ 7] : 30  pct : 48.387096
 totaldays[ 8] : 62  flyingdays[ 8] :  7  pct : 11.290322
 totaldays[ 9] : 60  flyingdays[ 9] : 38  pct : 63.333332
 totaldays[10] : 62  flyingdays[10] : 62  pct : 100.000000
 totaldays[11] : 60  flyingdays[11] : 50  pct : 83.333328
 totaldays[12] : 62  flyingdays[12] : 48  pct : 77.419350
```

See what you have and let me know.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for the detailed response. Thanks to your help and going over my lesson I understand the logic of how to do the problem. I'm still trying to figure out how to correctly scan in the values. I didn't really undestand your hint on how to efficiently read both arrays using 'while  (fscanf (fp, "%hhu %hhu %hu %f", &m, &d, &y, &t) == 4) ' so instead I wanted to do each array separately. I started with the total days array. If I run a for loop: for (m=0; m<12; m++) followed with fscanf(fp...", I can't seem to understand how to make the counter add one per line

Comment: OK, glad to help, give me a minute and I'll add a bit more to the answer.

Comment: If I use your while loop example I believe I have to follow it with the for loop for the months for (m=0; m<12; m++) and then under that I'm not sure what is next. I have totaldays[m]++; but I'm sure that's incorrect. This is my code so far. I'm setting a max and min and trying to get the main task accomplished before setting up the user inputted data and file name https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d97a998c3d3cefcb2465

Comment: Now I bet you can make a bit more sense out of it `:)`

Comment: Hey David I really appreciate all the time you've put into helping me. I feel like this assignment is really complex compared to the lesson and previous assignments. I still cannot seem to get the program to work correctly. The code I had written was giving me all 0's for the percentages. I tried your completed code and I'm getting incorrect values for the percentages such as month 1: 411.3 percent. The recommendation does seem to be correct in recommending the highest .

Comment: I'm looking through the calculation portion to see if I can see what the error is now.

Comment: Double-check everything. You should be able to simply copy/paste my example and get the correct values (as long as you and I are using the exact same datafile from your assignment). You are compiling normally? `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -o dragonflight dragonflight.c` You know the saying, garbage-in / garbage-out, double check your data file. Double-check the array index offsets `m-1`, `m+1`, etc.. I'll dump intermediate values for you.

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? It shouldn't matter, but if you are on windows, we may have to tweak a few variable types or the way we cast the results.

Comment: David, I found that line float pct = (float)flyingdays[m]/totaldays[m] * 100 isn't calculating correctly. I added this line right after the pct calculation: if (pct > 100) {printf("%d %d %d\n", m, flyingdays[m], totaldays[m]);} and this printed out an abnormally large value for flyingdays[m] of 255 which gives the percentage of 455 I was getting from dividing by the total days of 56.

Comment: I'm on codeblocks and windows. So knowing that flyingdays[m] isn't calculating correctly I looked at the lines if (tl <= t && t <= th) and flyingdays[m-1]++; but I didn't see anything wrong. I tried rearranging t to be first in the && part but that didn't change anything

Comment: Oh boy, let's try the longer version `float pct = (float)flyingdays[m]/(float)totaldays[m] * 100.0;` If that doesn't work, we will change all `unsigned char` to `unsigned int`, just in case codeblocks isn't handling the type promotion properly (stranger things have happened). **Do you have all the same values stored in the arrays as I show as far as the days go?**

Comment: adding the second (float) cast to totaldays[m] did not change my percentages and I'm still getting an abnormally large value printed from flyingdays[m] when I test it by printing it out

Comment: The most probable cause there is you are either writing beyond the end of the array or reading from beyond the end of the array due to an index hiccup.  (e.g. reading or writing to `flightdays[12]`). Is it all `flyingdays[m]` or the first or last? How large is too large?

Comment: It doesn't look like the values in my arrays are correct my values (index, flying  days, total days) (0,255,62)(1,255,56)(2,255,62)(3,59,60)(4,59,62)(5,29,60)(6,30,62)(7,7,62)(8,38,60)(9,62,62)(10,60,60)(11,62,62)

Comment: Holy crap. That's `FUBAR`.  Obviously `255` is the max that an `unsigned char` can possibly be. That tells me you are overflowing the type somewhere. No, your `flyingdays` are actually the `totaldays`, so you are reading garbage from the file. Show me your `fscanf` statement. If it is the same as mine, that means codeblocks cannot handle the size modifier `%hhu` when reading values.

Comment: changing all the unsigned char to unsigned int seems to have fixed everything

Comment: Yes, it's frigging Codeblocks!! It is not handling the type modifier `%hhu` telling it to read an `unsigned char` and it was trying to stuff a full `unsigned int` (`4-bytes`) into the (`1-byte`) `unsigned char`. Both codeblocks and the windows VS compiler suffer small issues like that. Linux really will spoil you when it comes to standards compliance. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Thank you so much David, I will be working through this to make sure I fully grasp these concepts. If you have any suggestions on  how to make this second nature it would be appreciated. Have a good night!

Comment: Same way you make math second nature, do problem after problem after problem -- and never settle for 'close enough'. Always strive to write the code as cleanly, flexibly and robustly as possible. Never be afraid to 'look it up'. Look at how the C functions take and return values, and always be willing to ask, what can I do to make my code better. After a while, you realize you are no longer struggling with C, but will begin to start playing it like an instrument. That is when you know you finally understand the *Art* of programming. Good luck.